Drag and drop not working (not allowed sign keeps on appearing)
I'm trying to create a simple where I can drag and drop images. But the code doesn't    seem be working, i don't know what the issue is. Thank you for you help everyone.
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QLabel, QVBoxLayout, QWidget
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt

class DragDropTest(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle('Drag and Drop Test')
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 400, 300)

        # Create a central widget and set the layout on it
        central_widget = QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)
        
        self.label = QLabel("Drag an image file here", self)
        self.label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        
        layout = QVBoxLayout(central_widget)
        layout.addWidget(self.label)

        # Accept drops for the central widget
        central_widget.setAcceptDrops(True)

    def dragEnterEvent(self, event):
        if event.mimeData().hasUrls():
            event.acceptProposedAction()
            self.label.setText("Drop the file here")
        else:
            event.ignore()

    def dragLeaveEvent(self, event):
        self.label.setText("Drag an image file here")

    def dropEvent(self, event):
        self.label.setText("File dropped!")
        for url in event.mimeData().urls():
            file_path = url.toLocalFile()
            self.label.setText(f"File path: {file_path}")
            # Additional code to handle the file

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    demo = DragDropTest()
    demo.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

